# Como salvar os campos selecionados em um CheckListBox C#?

Tags: c#, webforms

O meu programa contém dois `CheckListBox`: o `chkLstBoxTabela` contém as tabelas do meu BD e o `chkLstBoxColunas` contém as colunas da tabela que foi selecionada no `chkLstBoxTabela`, de modo que quando selecionamos uma tabela são exibidas as suas colunas.

Preciso que quando eu selecione outra tabela fique salvo as colunas selecionadas da tabela anterior. Seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: É possível, mas pra que a gente te oriente corretamente, precisamos que você coloque o código desenvolvido até então no corpo da sua pergunta. Poderia editá-la, por favor?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso usando `Session`.

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia usar a `Session` para esse tipo de coisa. Lembre-se que ela ocupa espaço no servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valeu pelas sugestões. 
Resolvi o problema criando uma flag na minha classe coluna de modo que quando eu marco uma coluna do chkLstBoxColunas ele seta a flag para true. Quando vou carregar o chkLstBoxColunas verifico a flag e marco os campos já selecionados.